# High-cardinality UUID: how/where to store?

Tags: database, time, uuid

I have lots of devices, each identified by a unique UUID. For each device, I have one or more timeseries data (potentially up to millions of entries).

What's the best way to store these entries? Whatever I do, it seems to me that:

- either I store the UUID of the device with each time series entry, which wastes a lot of space,
- or I store data for a device in a table named after its UUID, which means creating thousands of tables.

Any other option? Would people use intermediate mapping tables for this?
It can't be changed now, but would have it been better if a simple integer id was chosen for the devices instead of a UUID?

Data points have a varying granularity, which varies from one point every 30 seconds to one point every minute. This will be used to query over device + time range, with time range spanning from a few months down to a few hours worth of data.
Data is written once and read many times, so read performance is definitely more important.
Queries will always be for a single device, never for multiple devices together (it's to generate graphs).
The order of magnitude for the data is not huge, but still significant. Data points have a resolution between 30 and 60 seconds, and the data will be populated as follows: since each device has a backlog of data (currently only local to the device) which stores several years of values (eg 10 years), first all the backlogs will be read from the devices and written to the database, which, depending on the resolution, will already make for (assuming 10 years) about 500k to 1M entries *per device*, and it's just the beginning: subsequently, there will be periodic updates that will bring in new data points (ie, only those newer than those already stored in the db) with the same resolution.
There are currently about 40k devices (expected to grow), for an initial count of between 20 billion to 40 billion time entries if my math is correct.

So if we save the device ID with each entry, using 128, 64 or 32 bits can make a substantial difference in terms of storage space needed (or zero bits even, if we go with the per-device table option, which however seems to be unpopular).

As for the actual db to use, this is a new project so I'm considering a few products, timescaledb and questdb among them, but I'm open to suggestions.
Since the devices db already exists and uses UUIDs to identify devices, the only constraint is that we must support the UUID to be able to link the time series with a given device.

An extra bonus point would be the ability to summarize data on the fly, without having to do it in code (if 3 months of data are requested, the graph shown to the user will have daily values, so it wouldn't make sense to send 30-second points there). Similarly, if one day interval is requested, it would be nice to send hourly data, etc.

EDIT: Even if benchmarking found that storing the UUID with each timeseries entry performs better, I'd still be interested in opinions as I might not have all the needed storage space available, or at least not yet.

Comment: I have taken all the requirements listed in your question about how you're going to read this data and taking them all together, I conclude you can store the data in `/dev/null`. Or put another way: how you store stuff depends on how you're going to read it.

Comment: What does used space on disk or number of tables have to do with the way data is read? But anyway, it's not difficult to deduce what a time series data would be read for...in this case, it will be used for graphs, over varying length of time. How? Using HTTP queries.

Comment: It does really depend on how you plan to access the data. Do you need to query by time? Correlate multiple time series? Is write or read performance more important? Or will you always read the entire time series in one go? Time series data can often be compressed well, and that can help performance. But it is difficult to combine compression and fast random access.

Comment: @JonasH thanks. Read performance is definitely more important here. Queries are by device + time interval, although the interval can be wide (from a few months down to a few hours worth of data).

Comment: What kind of database? A heavyweight relational DB like Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL or PostgreSQL? Or some NowSQL? Or a lightweight file database like SQLite or MS Access? Or are you free to choose? It would help a lot if you tell us more about the order of magnitude of the numbers (~ number of devices, number of parallel readers & writers, are all writes for a device completed until the data is read, are most queries separated by device, or do you expect queries across the time series of different devices? .

Comment: ... in case you intend to answer this, please don't do it by a comment - instead use the "edit" button under the question.

Comment: @DocBrown Done.

Answer (score 6):

Ten years ago I would have used a integer value for the timeseries id in the database, and a separate table to map the UUID as a string (or other public id) to the internal id.

Now we have UUID types in databases, at least in some, and most native integers are 64 bits, so the difference is still there but only 128 vs 64 bits. Performance of queries is better than strings, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453329/1527 , but you still may find you want to use smaller integers and paged results for very large data (again, I did that ten years ago as it was the only way to get the data through the bandwidth available between the database and the application server, but last time I compared that with Postgres timescaledb, they were within a few percent of each other, so now-a-days I wouldn't go that route).

Also modern systems allow for automatic partitioning and support many tables, so that shouldn't be a worry.

Either way, I would try different approaches and measure the actual performance would be in your storage and querying scenarios. You probably will need to dive quite deep into performance and partitioning, and that means doing so for the database engine you choose, or potentially for multiple engines if you don't yet have the knowledge to make that choice.

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed taking a look at timescaledb, among other options. Even 128 vs 64 bits adds up quickly when you have millions of entries, I'd say. In this case there are many devices, but in the order of tens of thousands, certainly a 32-bit integer would also have sufficed, which means even more space saved.

Comment: I had an answer showing the "ten years ago" approach but I think this one is more on spot, especially the last paragraph: Measure and compare different approaches, a variation on "no premature optimization".

Comment: Support for efficient UUID indexing varies across databases so RTM.  Standard integer indexing can be very problematic with UUIDs and the type of UUID you are using can have implications for lookup performance.

Comment: I would start to think about how you want to query or report on these millions of millions of rows. if everything is demoralised to some data lake anyway do you save anything at all? would it be better just to use big csv files or something?

Comment: @ewan thanks. No, unfortunately it'll have to be self-hosted.

Answer (score 1):

An option may be to store the each time series as a binary blob in a common table. This can reduce the data size drastically since you only store the UUID once, and the data can often be compressed to further reduce the size. In many cases time series data can be compressed very well.

There are some major downsides with this approach. It will be difficult to add individual samples. Querying by time will also be more difficult. There are ways problems can be handled, like doing decompression & filtering on the client. But the cost/benefit will largely depend on your specific usage patterns. I would recommend doing some tests and calculations to compare the amount of data you would need to load for your typical usage scenario.

If you really want to maximize read performance you might want to do things like storing data in multiple resolution levels. Similar to how many image compression methods have a "progressive" encoding option. But again, such methods typically do not play well with continuously updated data.

Do note that "millions of entries" is not really that many. Storing just the UUId would mean 16Mb per million entries, not a huge amount, even if this will increase somewhat with indices etc. I would recommend trying the simplest possible solution first and evaluate if that works *well enough*. You should also consider the cost of your time relative to that of simply buying more hardware.

Comment: Thanks. To put things in perspective, for _a single_ device with 10 yrs worth of data at 30 seconds/point, storing 128 bits per entry would amount to abt 170MB/device just for the IDs, vs 42MB/device for 32-bit ints. Given there are 37812 devices as of now, and expected to grow, that would mean saving about 4.7 TB for the whole data, not a HUGE amount of data but still quite a lot. If I create a table per UUID, that would reduce to zero.

Comment: And before you ask, no, it won't take 10 years to get to that point, since on the first reading we would read the device backlog, which might already have several years worth of data.